# how to save image in DCIM folder of external SDCARD in android 11?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am saving image in DCIM folder of internal storage by using below code:

```
    public Uri saveBitmap(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final Bitmap bitmap,
                      @NonNull final Bitmap.CompressFormat format,
                      @NonNull final String mimeType,
                      @NonNull final String displayName) throws IOException {

    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = null;

    try {
        final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, values);

        if (uri == null)
            throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");

        try (final OutputStream stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri)) {
            if (stream == null)
                throw new IOException("Failed to open output stream.");
         
            if (!bitmap.compress(format, 95, stream))
                throw new IOException("Failed to save bitmap.");
        }

        return uri;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

        if (uri != null) {
            // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
            resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
        }

        throw e;
    }
}
```

now i want to save image in DCIM folder of external SDCARD but i don't know how to do it.

i know that i have to made changes in this line :

```
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
```

but `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` always return DCIM Folder of internal storage.

Comment: `final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;` You only have to change that collection.  `MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(name)` With name for example a value like  1CD3-23ED (or 1cd3-23ed) obtained from `MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames(context);`

Comment: `know that i have to made changes in this line :` No. As that is all relative.

Comment: `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM always return DCIM Folder of internal storage.` No. It's just equal to "DCIM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain the existing Volumes using the new [MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#getExternalVolumeNames(android.content.Context)) API method, introduced in API 29.

The next example obtains the list of volumes, and tries all of them, prioritizing first any attached SD-card and finally using internal storage if no SD-cards are found or fail to save.

You don't need to make any changes to the **RELATIVE_PATH** content value, as such is relative to the selected volume.

Also note that I've changed **saveBitmap** with a **Nullable** return, instead of throwing an exception on failure. Change this according to your requirements.

```
@NonNull
private List<Uri> getContentUris(@NonNull final Context context) {

    final List<String> allVolumes = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add the internal storage volumes as last resort.
    // These will be kept at the bottom of the list if
    // any SD-card volumes are found
    allVolumes.add(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
    allVolumes.add(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);

    // Obtain the list of volume name candidates

    final Set<String> externalVolumeNames = MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames(context);

    for (final String entry : externalVolumeNames) {
        // If the volume is "not" already cached in the list,
        // then is an SD-card, so prioritize it by adding it 
        // at the top of the list
        if (!allVolumes.contains(entry))
            allVolumes.add(0, entry);
    }

    // Finally resolve the target Image content Uris

    final List<Uri> output = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final String entry : allVolumes) {
        output.add(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(entry));
    }

    return output;
}

@Nullable
public Uri saveBitmap(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final Bitmap bitmap,
                      @NonNull final Bitmap.CompressFormat format,
                      @NonNull final String mimeType,
                      @NonNull final String displayName) {

    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    final List<Uri> contentUriList = getContentUris(context);

    for (final Uri contentUri : contentUriList) {
       
        Uri uri = null;

        try {
            uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, values);

            if (uri == null)
                throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");

            try (final OutputStream stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri)) {
                if (stream == null)
                    throw new IOException("Failed to open output stream.");

                if (!bitmap.compress(format, 95, stream))
                    throw new IOException("Failed to save bitmap.");
            }

            return uri;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to save in volume: " + contentUri);

            if (uri != null) {
                // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
                resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
            }

            // Do not throw, and try the next volume
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```