# How can I rename a folder I created in the shared storage?

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, scoped-storage

My app creates folders in the shared storage (DCIM/ and Pictures/ directories), which I want to be able to rename afterwards.

I save the images using MediaStore, the folders are created automatically.

> Android Q (and above) already takes care of creating the folders if
> they don’t exist. The example is hard-coded to output into the
> **DCIM** folder. If you need a sub-folder then append the sub-folder name as next:
>
> ```
> final String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + “YourSubforderName”;
> ```
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56990305/10226383

I just can't seem to figure out how to do it, is that even possible with scoped storage, do I need to use MediaStore or SAF?

I know before the change to scoped storage you could do it this way:

```
File oldfolder = new File("path of the old folder","old name");
File newfolder = new File("path of the new folder","new name");
oldfolder.renameTo(newfolder);
```

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be really grateful!

Comment: You did not tell how your app created those folders.

Comment: @blackapps To save the pictures I use MediaStore, the folders are created automatically if I specify a folder name.

Comment: Ok. At saving a file you specified RELATIVE_PATH i think. Did you try renameTo() already?